# How to set INGRESS_HOST and INGRESS_PORT and access GATEWAY_URL

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio

How to set INGRESS_HOST and INGRESS_PORT for a sample yaml file which is having its istio file created using automatic side car injection

I am using window 10 - Docker - kubernetes -Istio configuration.Installed kubectl,istioctl verions respectievly

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    name: http
  selector:
    app: helloworld
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-v1
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image: istio/examples-helloworld-v1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-v2
  labels:
    version: v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image: istio/examples-helloworld-v2
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000




apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: helloworld-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - helloworld-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /hello
    route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        port:
          number: 5

010
```

Getting 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable when trying to hit my sample created service

Answer (score 0):

Please first verify your selector labels are perfect and your service is connected to deployment[POD].

You have 'version: v1' and 'version: v2' in deployment selector but it's not at service. That's why service is giving output 503 unavailable. if the issue in pod or service then i will be giving 502 bad gateway or something.

Istio traffic work like

```
ingress-gateway -> virtual-service -> destination-rule [optional] -> service

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - helloworld-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          exact: /hello
      route:
      - destination:
          host: helloworld
          port:
            number: 5000  <--- change
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO @Sreedhar!

> How to set INGRESS_HOST and INGRESS_PORT

these two environment variables are not adjustable inside of manifest files (static files), that you use to create Deployments->Pods on K8S cluster. They serve just as a placeholders to ease the end-users an access to the application just deployed on Istio-enabled Kubernetes cluster from outside. Values of INGRESS_HOST/INGRESS_PORT are filled out based on information, which is auto-generated by cluster during creation of cluster resources, and available only in live objects.

Where the ingress takes its IP address from, you can read in official documentation here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

For the Bad gateway issue, as suggested previously by @Harsh Manvar, you have specified invalid port in VirtualService (5000 => 5010)